# Reduce Fill Image from Two Sides

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have set **Image Type** to **Filled** because I want to reduce the size of my filling area.
On the left side, you can see my progress bar within the attached image.

Within the inspector, you can clearly see I have set **Fill Origin** from **Top** so image size gets reduced from the bottom.

Now one twist I want, I want to reduce an image from both sides top and bottom, I have already played with **Image** component different values but I can't able to get success.

Overall I want to reduce the size of the image from the top and bottom.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried just using the scale value of the image?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways you can achieve this effect:

You can instead change the Y scale of the image, whilst the Y pivot is 0.5 this will make it shrink from top to bottom, but this will only work if the sprite looks the same even if shrunk down.

If your sprite's shape won't allow for changing the scale like that, you could also split it into 2 sprites at the midpoint and put them next to each other, and then have the top side fill from bottom, and the bottom side fill from top.